# Why does my iphone weirdly autocorrect any in-app text field when I type out my email with '@@@'?

Tags: ios

This is bizarre but it's been plaguing me for over a year now. Whenever there is an in-app text-field and I type in my email address, the iphone autocorrects my email to '@@@'. It appears as a suggestion/hint but I rarely can dismiss it without it actually replacing the email I had just typed with @@@. This started about 18 months ago. It's driving me batty. It only does it with my email address and only seems to do it in apps - I have noticed it happening in netflix as well as the many Ionic apps I have developed. How do I fix and why does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check your setting app first.

- General > Keyboard > Text Replacement

Using @@ to expand to your primary email and using @@@ for a secondary and so on is common practice. Perhaps you set that up, but in reverse. I believe I heard that from a podcast or some blog post a while back but cannot recall. I have adopted that shortcut and it’s super handy.

Here is a blog crediting Rene Ritchie and the author, Patrick Welker, for the general awareness and specific use case of multiple @ to represent emails respectively.

- http://rocketink.net/2014/09/ios-@@-shortcut.html
- http://m.imore.com/how-to-setup-text-keyboard-shortcuts-iphone-ipad-ios

Yours turning the actual mail into a shortcut, not so much useful.